# Sudden problems with iptables not running

Tags: centos, iptables, xen

I've got a sudden issue with iptables not running on my CentOS 5.8/DirectAdmin XenVPS. All I have done today is install PHP APC and run an update (although I admittedly didn't pay much attention today - I usually do). Iptables has been running fairly smoothly since I installed it over 6 months ago.

Basically when I try to run iptables -L it tells me:

> iptables v1.3.5: can't initialize iptables table `filter': iptables
>   who? (do you need to insmod?) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to
>   be upgraded.

I've looked around and tried a few things and it *appears* that maybe my kernel doesn't have the modules loaded? I've been [reading this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/commonproblems.html) and tried the two commands they suggest to no avail. Except there does appear to be a mismatch on one bit of output:

```
-bash-3.2# cd /lib/modules
-bash-3.2# ls
2.6.18-194.32.1.el5xen  2.6.18-238.5.1.el5xen  2.6.18-274.7.1.el5xen  2.6.39.1-cs-domU
2.6.18-238.12.1.el5xen  2.6.18-238.9.1.el5xen  2.6.37.2-cs-domU       3.0.1-cs-domU
-bash-3.2# depmod -a
WARNING: Couldn't open directory /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.18.1.el5xen: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.18.1.el5xen/modules.dep.temp for writing: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean the versions are out of sync? If so, what are my next steps to getting this fixed?

As you can probably tell I am still learning how to manage my server so please be very clear in all advice.

Many thanks :)

EDIT:
Results of running uname -a as requested.

> Linux server1.fortheinter.net 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Feb 9
>   13:27:02 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT 2:
Results of checking the package list.

```
-bash-3.2# yum list | grep kernel
kernel-headers.x86_64     2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          installed
kernel.x86_64             2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-debug.x86_64       2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-debug-devel.x86_64 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-devel.x86_64       2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-doc.noarch         2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-xen.x86_64         2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
kernel-xen-devel.x86_64   2.6.18-308.1.1.el5          updates
yum-kernel-module.noarch  1.1.16-21.el5.centos        base
```

Comment: Was your kernel one of the things that was upgraded?

Comment: `uname -a` would be helpful. Seems like the kernel your VPS is boot (I assume it is 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5xen) misses its part (modules).

Comment: Not sure if the kernel was updated as I was distracted and not paying attention to the update particularly. Added the uname -a result to the question.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (re)installing kernel 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5xen within VPS.

Comment: How do I do that? I understand that is a broad question so feel free to point me in the direction of a tutorial on it. EDIT: Is it even possible as it is something setup by my VPS provider?

Comment: if you have root access, you could try `yum list | grep kernel` and see which options you have in repos (look at 'updates' in particular for this version) and which kernels you have installed. Have not much experience with xen, but maybe this is because your VPS was booted from kernel on host machine which is not installed in guest OS. Actually, you may not need vmlinuz itself in your guest but you probably still need /lib/modules for kernel which appears in `uname -a` output.

Comment: I've checked the yum list and it seems to make things more confusing... I've added the output to the post above and as you can see it shows another version entirely. I also did a search for xen packages, which shows some called xen-libs in updates.

Comment: try `wget http://ftp.riken.go.jp/Linux/centos/5.7/updates/x86_64/RPMS/kernel-xen-2.6.18-274.12.1.el5.x86_64.rpm; rpm -Uvh kernel-xen-2.6.18-274.12.1.el5.x86_64.rpm`. You can use another link if your preferred mirror has this particular package.

Comment: It downloads and then says "prepares" and the first step reaches 100% then it says "ls: /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf: No such file or directory". Is it worth trying to install one of these kernels listed in the updates? Or won't they add the missing modules?

Comment: So it doesn't get installed? If yes, that I think kernels from updates will fail to install either. The case here is that you need to have correspondence between version of running kernel and set of it's modules. Using modules from one kernel with another is highly discouraged. Try installing module-init-tools (`yum install module-init-tools`) and reattempt installing kernel.

Comment: Well this is bizarre... went to try what you suggested here and it told me that module-init-tools is already installed. So I ran iptables -L again and now it works! Had to restart iptables for it to load my rules but it is definitely working. I can only presume it was something the provider did and has now fixed. :S Will mark it as the answer because it will be valuable to others with the same issue. Thanks for all your help. :)